# Class 'PayPal\Rest\ApiContext' not found

Tags: php, web, dynamic, paypal

I'm having a little problem with my php code, since I'm using paypal api for e-payement.

I get the following error message :

> Fatal error: Class 'PayPal\Rest\ApiContext' not found in F:\wamp64\www\tests\form4\start.php on line 7

```
<?php
require '/vendor/autoload.php'; 
define('SITE_URL', 'paypal4.php');
$paypal = new \PayPal\Rest\ApiContext(new 
\PayPal\Auth\OAuthTokenCredential('ID','ID'));

?>
```

Any help please ?

Comment: where in your files is `PayPal\Rest\ApiContext`? How is it included in start.php?

Comment: Oh it was indeed a path problem ! I placed a folder that has the same name, and that's why it didn't work. Thanks a lot :D

Comment: That's no problem :)